# algorithm for app shaking in iphone's delete mode

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios

Does anyone out there know if there's an open source algorithm that manipulates an object's (x,y) coordinates similar to the iPhone's delete mode on the home screen where all the app icons are shaking? We're trying to simulate this using javascript/jquery so we prefer the algorithm be in js, but I imagine that it wouldn't be that difficult to port if this algorithm has already been developed but in another language.

Comment: Let me see if I can come up with something for you. It should be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember off the top of my head exactly how the iPhone's shaking in delete mode looked, but hopefully you can tweak the values in the following script to suit your purposes. It provides random X/Y movement in an element, provided that element has the class `shaking` on it.

```
function randomRange(lowerRange, upperRange) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (upperRange - lowerRange + 1)) + lowerRange;
}

function shakeElement(elem) {
    if ($.data($(elem)[0], "pos") === undefined) {
        $.data($(elem)[0], "pos", {
            top: $(elem).position().top,
            left: $(elem).position().left
        });
    }

    if($(elem).hasClass("shaking")) {
        $(elem).animate({
            top: $.data($(elem)[0], "pos").top + randomRange(-8, 8),
            left: $.data($(elem)[0], "pos").left + randomRange(-8, 8)
        }, 100, function() {
            shakeElement(this);
        });
    }
}

$(".shaking").each(function() {
    shakeElement(this);
});
```

Here's a working [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HeyJavascript/pS7bx/) for you.
    ​

Comment: Interesting. Seems to work but definitely not as polished as the iPhone :)

Comment: You can play with the speed of the animations and the distance the divs travel to polish it up a bit. I just threw some quick values in there to see if it works.